# split mint money metaplex

Tags: metadata, solana, nft, metaplex

I am new to blockchain technology and I have a certain issue with spliting into multiple wallet the mint money with metaplex

I want to know if it is possible to have some wallets that will get a percentage of the primary sale (mint) but will not get any royalties ?
And if it is possible how to do it ? (Json attribute in the metadata ? )

Here is my json metadata :

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "symbol": "symbol",
    "description": "Collection of 2 NFTS on the blockchain. this is the number 1 out of 2.",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 500, // Here only public key 1 gets the royalties 
    "image": "1.png",
    "attributes": [
        {"trait_type:": "Background", "value": "Door"},
        {"trait_type:": "Ninja", "value": "Red"}
    ],
    "properties": {
        "creators": [
            {"address": "public key 1", "share": 50},
            {"address": "public key 2", "share": 50}
               
        ],
        "files": [{"uri": "1.png", "type": "image/png"}]

    },
    "collection": {"name": "Lavish Fighters", "family": "Rare"}

}
```

I do know we can't comment in Json it is just to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creators on the json field inside the metadata are [deprecated on the newers standards.](https://docs.metaplex.com/token-metadata/specification#token-standards) Also those creators are just for secondary markets royalty share.

You can take a look at [Hydra](https://hydra-docs.glasseaters.xyz) its a wallet of wallets that work to split mint funds between different wallets. [Here is a Hydra-UI](https://github.com/cardinal-labs/hydra-ui) that can work on mainnet.

Comment: thank you very much just to be sure this Hydra wallet will take place as the treasury account right?

Comment: yes, exactly. Just put it in the config as treasury.